# Does RIP-relative addressing require 16-byte aligned?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64

The test is on 64-bit/x86 Ubuntu 12.04. With `GCC` 4.6.3.

So basically I am manipulating some x64 assembly code. And I observed that [RIP-relative addressing](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/introduction-to-x64-assembly/) require the absolute address to be 16-byte aligned.

Here is an example when debugging using `gdb`:

```
0x40f38d <S_0x40F614+61>        xorpd  0x84d3(%rip),%xmm0   # 0x417868 <S_0x417DE0>
```

This memory reference to address `0x417868` fail (segmentation fault), as this address is only 8-byte aligned.

```
0x40f38d <S_0x40F614+61>        xorpd  0x8a4b(%rip),%xmm0   # 0x417de0 <S_0x417DE0>
```

This memory reference can work, as address `0x417de0` is 16 byte aligned.

This is my observation, and I didn't find any official materials discussing about this issue. Could anyone tell me

1. Is this 16-byte alignment requirement universally true?
2. If so, then does any official document/manual talking about this?

Comment: It's the `xorpd` instruction that requires 16-byte alignment for the memory operand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the `xorpd` instruction. It causes and Exception of type 4, which happens when you specify an unaligned memory location without the VEX prefix.  (So `vxorpd` wouldn't fault on unaligned.)

[image: Intel Manuals]

However, it's not the only one, there are about 106 more instructions that cause the same thing.

Comment: Memory operands of legacy SSE instructions must be aligned (except for the obvious exceptions), VEX-encoded instructions can take an unaligned operand.

Comment: @harold I didn't know that. According to this, is there any general rule saying when the exception occurs?

Comment: @user35443: Every m128 memory operand for non-VEX SSE instructions must be aligned or it will fault, except for instructions that specifically say they're for unaligned data.  (e.g. `movdqu`).  This is what @harold meant by "obvious".  VEX-coded instructions never require alignment, except `movdqa` / `movaps` / `movapd`.  (So you should always use `movdqu`, because it's just as fast when the data IS aligned, on CPUs new enough to support AVX.)